# ComboBox ItemsSource binding within a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to bind a combobox to a list of items (ObservableCollection) on my viewmodel. If I use something like this on my view:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Teams}" DisplayMemberPath="TeamName" />
```

everything is OK. But if I take that same combobox and use it as part of a datatemplate on another template used as the items template for a listbox, nothing shows up in the list. Pseudocode example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="test">
  <TextBlock Text="Team:" />
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Teams}" DisplayMemberPath="TeamName" />
</DataTemplate>
```

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="GamesCV" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource test}" />
```

I thought maybe I needed to add a relative source so I tried that, but no luck. I also tried giving my UserControl a name and using that as the ElementName on my combobox binding. I can't imagine this is as hard as I'm making it. I'm probably missing something obvious. Can anyone help? I can give more specifics if necessary, I'm just pressed for time right now.

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the Output Window in VS during runtime? Do the items in the GamesCV collection have a property named `Teams`?

Comment: Is your DataContext ok ? Your GamesCV is a (observable) Collection, and one of the item of that collection (a GameCV) has a 'Teams' pblic property which is a (observable)Collection of items having a public property TeamName ? try checking this first. You might first add another property of a GameCV to check your test DataTemplate's DataContext (?GameName?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you forgot the `DataContext` in the path? If you use `RelativeSource` you target a framework element and no longer the `DataContext`, so this should do it:

```xml
{Binding DataContext.Teams, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}
```

Also if you have trouble with bindings [check for errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), they will tell you *all* you need to know.

Comment: That got it! Thanks, H.B. - I thought it would be something fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

For UWP I got it like this

```
   <GridView x:Name="abc" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Companies,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></GridView>
```